# JavaScript comma separated join a set number of elements in a Array without jQuery

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm not sure if jQuery would be a factor but since I'm using Vue and Quasar I wanted to put that out front to not use it.

I know that if I want to convert an Array to a comma separated string I would use

```
  Array.join(',')
```

and that would give me a nice comma separated string. But is there a way without doing a loop to only join a set number of elements?

I need to take an array of publication ID's remove the duplicates and then only combine 200 of them.  My list could be as long as 10,000 but the web service that I am sending the data can only handle 200 at a time.

```
    30310060,30166592,29704517,29662190,29533787,28114741,27456065,27208808,26208975
```

and then go back and pick up another 200

I need to convert the string to JSON to send it to the web server.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work?

```
joinFirstN = function(array,n,separator){
   sample = array.slice(0,n);
   return(sample.join(separator);)
}
```

This slices the first n elements into an array, and then joins it into a string.
So you would do something like:

```
joinFirstN(array,200,",");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using anything but ES6 (no libraries), you can use an object to de-dupe values in an array. Then, you can use an async function to recursively take any number of elements at a time, submit them to the server, and after you get a response, submit the next batch. This same pattern could be extended to submit multiple batches at once if your server can handle that, vs. doing each batch serially.

```
//Basically build an object out of the ids. This will dedupe them all.
//Finally, only take the keys (or values, whichever)
const uniqueIds = Object.keys(ids.reduce((ids, id) => {
  ids[id] = id
  return ids
}, {}))

const submitInBatches = async (ids, batchSize) => {
  //If you have no ids, you're done.
  if (ids.length === 0) return

  //Get the next batch of ids, and submit them
  batch = ids.slice(0, batchSize)
  const results = await fetch(`/your/service?${batch.join(',')}`)
  //Do something with the results

  //Then take all of the remaining ids and recursively call them
  return submitInBatches(ids.slice(batchSize), batchSize)
}

submitInBatches(uniqueIds, 200)
```

Comment: `Array.from(new Set(ids))` another way to de-dupe.